# Which Python (sqlalchemy) mssql DB API works in Cygwin?

Tags: python, sql-server, cygwin, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy on Cygwin with a MSSQL backend but I cannot seem to get any of the MSSQL Python DB APIs installed on Cygwin. Is there one that is known to work?

Answer (score 0):

FreeTDS + unixodbc + pyodbc stack will work on Unix-like systems and should therefore work just as well in Cygwin. You should use version 8.0 of TDS protocol. This can be configured in connection string.

Comment: Cygwin is great as a handy Unix shell in Windows. Using it a destination platform for production quality Python developed software is probably a mistake but I cannot judge not knowing all circumstances. Pyodbc works just as well in UNIX, native Windows so I would be surprised you cannot make it work on Cygwin.